# How to know which queries are consuming the most of cpu in a shared hosting?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a PHP + MySQL web application that runs on a typical shared hosting, and I would like to know what queries are most called and what quantity of resources are consuming. This way, I'll focus to the most expensives queries to optimize the resources or detect badly optimized queries.

For example:

```
query1 - 500 times - 50% (or 44seconds or any measuring criteria)
query2 - 4000 times  - 20%
query3 - 300 times - 1%
...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't post the name of the hosting for not doing spam. If you prefer to know it, please let me know

Comment: If you have any database abstraction layer, you can include logging in the query function - log the query, the time in the beginning and the end of the function, and (possibly with md5 hash of the query) - how many times the query was called. You can also download the web site on your local server, install xhprof and profile your web site.

Comment: Are you using a specific database abstraction layer, have you coded one your own or have you spread `mysq_query` commands across your whole code?

Comment: What PHP extension/driver fo you use for interaction with db?

Comment: I've used the PhpDao as a abastraction layer: http://phpdao.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example for PDO you can create class with simple structure like follwoing:

```
class DatabaseConnection extends PDO 
{

    private $queries = array();

    public function query($stmt)
    {
       $start_time = microtime(true);
       $result = parent::query($stmt);
       $end_time = microtime(true) - $start_time;

       $this->queries[] = array(
        'query' => $stmt,
        'time'  => $end_time
       );
       return $result;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could measure the queries' execution time and save that information into a table in the database along with debugging information like the query string itself, file and line where the query was executed and the number of results. The statistics could be calculated using this data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your host you may be able to enable the [Slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html) which will list any queries taking longer than x seconds.